# how to burn full hd movies (1080px720p) in DVD

Tags: video-editor, video-quality, software-recommendation, dvd, full-hd

How can i burn or write Full HD videos like (marriage videos) in 1080px720p in regular DVD. I tried many softwares but couldn't get the job done.

Answer (score 4):

[DVD Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video) is limited to Standard Def, not High Def (HD).  Blu-Ray overcomes that limitation.  Alternatively you can use the DVD as a filesystem and play arbitrary media using a computer.  But as a media container itself, the DVDs limits are very restricted.

Answer (score 0):

The format is called [AVCHD Disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVCHD#AVCHD_as_distribution_format). You can also author Blu-Ray file structure onto a DVD. Depending on the Blu-Ray player you have, it may prefer one or another or play both, although I assume that nowadays Blu-Ray players play pretty much any variation.

Besides file structure, mind the resolution and frame rate. 1080p60 / 1080p50 is not officially supported by Blu-Ray Disc spec, but usually is played by the players. In the 60 Hz land, 720p30 is also not officially supported (720p60 is the proper format for 720-line video) but usually is played by modern players. If your player is not multi-region, it may reject some frame rates, like it may not play 1080p25 Blu-Ray or AVCHD Disk on a 60 Hz machine even if your disk is not region-locked and the machine can play bare 25p files like AVI or MKV.